# C# using on-screen keyboard to fill up form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm creating a winform application which require the windows on screen keyboard to fill up a text box. I have 4 text boxes. I created 4 textbox click event to pop up the keyboard when user click the textbox.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Click += textBox1_Click;
        textBox2.Click += textBox2_Click;
        textBox3.Click += textBox3_Click;
        textBox4.Click += textBox4_Click;
    }

    private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk");
    }

    private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk");
    }

    private void textBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk");
    }

    private void textBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("osk");
    }
```

The problem I face is, if I first click on textbox1 after running the app, the keyboard will only able to type into textbox1. After that if I click other textBox, it won't be able to type anything in.

Same as if I first click on textbox2 after running the app, the keyboard will only able to type into textbox2. After that if I click other textBox, it won't be able to type anything in.

Do you guys know what's wrong?

Comment: oh my I feel bad for you... for one thing you don't need to duplicate code, one handler can do, also you're looking for the Focus event, not Click. And then there is the winforms - one of the more not-so-good UI frameworks. Have you tried killing the osk process when you determine it's ok to do so (pressed enter, textbox lost focus etc)

Comment: When click textbox app starting and it's losing focus .then after click any textbox on form app start again and again textbox loosing focus.this situation again again happen

Comment: Have you considered creating your own keyboard form so you don't have to spawn out to an external program?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Add the following class to your project:

```
class TouchKeyboardProvider
{
    #region Private: Fields

    private readonly string _virtualKeyboardPath;

    #endregion

    #region ITouchKeyboardProvider Methods

    public TouchKeyboardProvider()
    {
        _virtualKeyboardPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles),
            @"Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(_virtualKeyboardPath))
        {
            _virtualKeyboardPath = _virtualKeyboardPath.Replace(" (x86)", string.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void ShowTouchKeyboard()
    {
        try
        {
            Process.Start(_virtualKeyboardPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Log error.
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void HideTouchKeyboard()
    {
        var nullIntPtr = new IntPtr(0);
        const uint wmSyscommand = 0x0112;
        var scClose = new IntPtr(0xF060);

        var keyboardWnd = FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", null);
        if (keyboardWnd != nullIntPtr)
        {
            SendMessage(keyboardWnd, wmSyscommand, scClose, nullIntPtr);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private: Win32 API Methods

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string sClassName, string sAppName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    #endregion

}
```

Then update your form to look something like this:

```
private readonly TouchKeyboardProvider touckKeyboardProvider = new TouchKeyboardProvider();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Click += textBox1_Click;
    textBox2.Click += textBox2_Click;
    textBox3.Click += textBox3_Click;
    textBox4.Click += textBox4_Click;
}

private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    touckKeyboardProvider.ShowTouchKeyboard();
}
....
```